# Behavior of compactly supported functions on boundary

Tags: real-analysis

Let $v(x, t): \mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function with compact support in $\mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty)$. Is there an example of a $v$ which does not satisfy $v(x, 0) = 0$?

Comment: Sure. Think of $\mathbb{R}\times[0,\infty)$ as the upper half plane of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and think about a smooth function that bumps up inside the unit half-circle around the origin and is zero outside.

Comment: It depends on how you define smoothness at the points $\mathbb R \times \{0\}$. Does it require smoothness in an open set containing the domain in $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$? If so, I would say no. If not, I would say yes. This is all assuming you are not allowed to extend the support into the enclosing open set.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, take a bump function. Like $\nu(x,t)=e^{-\frac{1}{1-t^2}-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}$ for $\lvert x\rvert,t<1$, 0 else. Then we have $\nu(x,0)\neq 0$ if $\lvert x\rvert<1.$